# could not execute statement in springMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

***this is my class***

```
package com.ducnd.pojo;


/**
 *
 * @author DucND
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Group1.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Group1 g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Group1.findById", query = "SELECT g FROM Group1 g WHERE g.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Group1.findByGroupname", query = "SELECT g FROM Group1 g WHERE g.groupname = :groupname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Group1.findByPurpose", query = "SELECT g FROM Group1 g WHERE g.purpose = :purpose")})
public class Group1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "groupname")
    private String groupname;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "purpose")
    private String purpose;
    @JoinTable(name = "user_group", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<User> userCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group1")
    private Collection<UserSpendingGroup> userSpendingGroupCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group1")
    private Collection<UserIncomeGroup> userIncomeGroupCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User userId;
```

**This is where I call the create group service**

```
@Controller
@ControllerAdvice
public class GroupController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/create-group")
    public String createGroup(Model model){
        
        model.addAttribute("group", new Group1());
        
        return "createGroup";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/create-group")
    public String createGroup(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value = "group")Group1 group, HttpSession session){
        User currentUser = (User) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
        group.setId(3);
        group.setUserId(currentUser);
        
        if(this.groupService.createGroup(group)==true){
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        return "createGroup";
    }
    
    
}
```

**this is the error I get**

*org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement*

***please someone help me to solve this problem***

Comment: You have declared Entity & all named query within entity. You might need to separate it by creating Repository & then declare all your named queries there? 

I am seeing you are getting `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement` meaning spring is unable to find query.

Comment: @AshishPatil `SQLGrammarException` does not mean the query is not found.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the code of the `GroupService` class (especially the `createGroup()` method)?

Comment: in the createGroup method I just save the object
`Session session = this.sessionFactory.getObject().getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.save(group);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
        }
        return false;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Know that *group* is a keyword in SQL. Try changing it to something else or use back ticks.